# C# Xamarin Forms - Invoking an event always returns null

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, event-handling

Hi everyone and sorry for my bad english.

I am developing an app on Xamarin Forms and I have encountered a problem with the `event invocation`.

I have a ContentView with various labels and two buttons to edit and delete the object in question. As you see I've tried various methods for event invocation, but the `EventHandler` is always null when I invocate it.

InstrumentCard.xaml.cs code:

```
public partial class InstrumentCard : ContentView
    {
        public event EventHandler<InstrumentEventArgs> DeleteClicked;
        public event EventHandler<InstrumentEventArgs> EditClicked;

        private Instrument _i;

        public InstrumentCard(Instrument i)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            _i = i;
            lblID.Text = i.ID.ToString();
            lblName.Text = i.Nome;
            lblQty.Text = $"Quantità: {i.Qty.ToString()}";
        }

        public Instrument GetInstrument()
        {
            return _i;
        }

        private void btnEdit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RaiseEdit(new InstrumentEventArgs { Instrument = _i});
        }

        private void RaiseEdit(InstrumentEventArgs args)
        {
            EditClicked?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

        private void btnDelete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeleteClicked?.Invoke(this, new InstrumentEventArgs
            {
                Instrument = _i
            });
        }
    }
```

MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        List<Instrument> instruments = new List<Instrument>();
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();
            
            Reload();
        }

        public async void Reload()
        { 
            List<Instrument> instruments = await App.Database.GetInstrumentsAsync();

            lblCounter.Text = $"Ci sono {instruments.Count} strumenti";

            if (instruments.Count == 0)
            {
                stcNoData.IsVisible = true;
                stcData.IsVisible = false;
                stcDock.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                stcNoData.IsVisible = false;
                stcData.IsVisible = true;
                stcDock.IsVisible = true;

                stcInstruments.Children.Clear();

                instruments.ForEach(instr =>
                {
                    InstrumentCard ic = new InstrumentCard(instr);
                    ic.DeleteClicked += Ic_DeleteClicked;
                    ic.EditClicked += Ic_EditClicked;

                    stcInstruments.Children.Add(new InstrumentCard(instr));
                });
            }
        }

        private void Ic_EditClicked(object sender, InstrumentEventArgs e)
        {
            Navigation.PushAsync(new AddInstrument(e.Instrument));
        }

        private void Ic_DeleteClicked(object sender, InstrumentEventArgs e)
        {
            stcInstruments.Children.Remove(sender as InstrumentCard);
            App.Database.DeleteInstrumentAsync(e.Instrument);
            Reload();
        }
}
```

When I debug the method...
[image]

I don't know what is wrong.
Thank you for your help

Comment: The events are null if they have no subscribers.

Comment: It means that nobody is subscribed to this event. Are you subscribing somewhere like 
EditClicked += ..... ?

Comment: Yes, subscription are in MainPage.xaml, but the flow stops before as you see in the screenshot. I tried replicating the same code in WPF and it works fine there.

Comment: show the rest of your code including xaml

Comment: Okay, I modified the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
instruments.ForEach(instr =>
{
  //here you create your instrument card
  InstrumentCard ic = new InstrumentCard(instr);
  ic.DeleteClicked += Ic_DeleteClicked;
  ic.EditClicked += Ic_EditClicked;
  //here you should use it but instead you create another one
  stcInstruments.Children.Add(new InstrumentCard(instr));
});
```

Just add your created instance where you are subscribed to events to the `StackPanel` (I am expecting that it is `StackPanel`)

```
stcInstruments.Children.Add(ic);
```